# How To Show Invalid Feedback Using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'm try to show the invalid feedback when the data is empty, when i'm using this code below and try to empty the field, it's work but the text of invalid feedback still showing it's disappear
disappear when im cliked again for one time.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#nama').blur(function() {
    if( $(this).val() != '' ) {
          $('#invalid-nama').css("display", "none");
    }else{
    $('#invalid-nama').css("display", "unset");
    }
});
</script>
```

and then i'm try to put && $(this).keypress(function()) into IF when the user typing but is not work

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#nama').blur(function() {
    if( $(this).val() != '' && $(this).keypress(function()) ) {
          $('#invalid-nama').css("display", "none");
    }else{
    $('#invalid-nama').css("display", "unset");
    }
});
</script>
```

so the problem is how to show invalid feedback when the data is empty and the invalid feedback disappear after using typing in the field, thankyou

Comment: `$(this).keypress(function()) )...` isn't something that you'd put in a condition. Please add ALL the relevant code (HTML and CSS) to your question so that we can replicate your issue and produce a working answer.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function errorMessageDisplay(){
  if($("#input").val() ==''){
    $("#errorMessage").text("Error").show();
  }else{
    $("#errorMessage").text("").hide();
  }
}

$("#input").blur(function(){
  errorMessageDisplay();
}).keyup(function(){
  errorMessageDisplay();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input" type="text" />
<div id="errorMessage" style="color: red"></div>
```

Comment: BTW, dont use keypress, keypress will have issue with first character when validate.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#nama').keyup(function() {
                if( $(this).val() != '') {
                      $('#invalid-nama').css("display", "none");
                }else{
                $('#invalid-nama').css("display", "unset");
                }
            });
        });
    </script> 
    <style type="text/css">
        #invalid-nama {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
    <form>
    <input type="text" id ="nama">
    <div id ="invalid-nama">Invalid</div>
    </form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```